# Shared component with specific click function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have created a shared component with below html:

```
<ion-row class="tableContainer">
  <table class="dataTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
         <!-- Some code is omitted -->

        <td *ngFor="let b of dataButtons" ngClass="{{b.styleClass}}">
            <ion-icon title={{b.styleClass}} name={{b.value}} (click)="clickTest()"></ion-icon>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</ion-row>
```

Then, I can use them in some pages like this:

```
<data-table [dataTitle]="invoicesDataTitle" [data]="invoicesData" [dataButtons]="invoicesDataButtons"></data-table>
```

My problem is that when I click the button, I want to call the method in the page that used `data-table`, instead of the method in `data-table` component. How can I do that?

Comment: I think this is covered in the docs: [Parent listens for child event](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event).

Comment: Correct. Either use an EventEmitter or a shared service. Depends on complexity of your Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to handle this is for your component to emit an event that the parent can listen to.

```
<data-table [dataTitle]="invoicesDataTitle" [data]="invoicesData" [dataButtons]="invoicesDataButtons" (dataClick)="currentPageHandler($event)"></data-table>
```

Inside your data-table.component.ts

```
@Output() dataClick = new EventEmitter<SomeEventType>();

clickTest() {
    this.dataClick.emit({data: someData} as SomeEventType);
}
```

Comment: By doing this, does each page now can have its own click method?

Comment: Yes, each parent component can implement its own click handler for what to do when the `ion-icon` element is clicked.